# Manifest unknown on docker pull

Tags: docker, docker-registry

i got this error at docker pull

```
$ docker-compose up -Vd 
Pulling sonic (quay.io/openware/baseapp:d61d0626)...
ERROR: manifest for quay.io/openware/baseapp:d61d0626 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown
```

i read another question in SO but this docker pull sometime works i dont have any idea why randomly docker return this error

Comment: If you go here and filter by 'd61d0626', there's no image matching that tag. It might have been removed. https://quay.io/repository/openware/baseapp?tag=latest&tab=tags

Answer (score 1):

The tag appears to not exist in the repository:

https://quay.io/repository/openware/baseapp?tab=tags

If you filter by `d61d...`, there is no corresponding image.

It has been deleted, perhaps because it contained a security issue.

You should consider using a different tag.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was that I was not using latest build number which I found later and replaced

```
docker run -p 5000:80 -e SDM_MASTER_KEY=00000000000000000000000000000000 icedevml/sdm-backend:build20220111-v2
Unable to find image 'icedevml/sdm-backend:build20220111-v2' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: manifest for icedevml/sdm-backend:build20220111-v2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown.
```

Checked the github repository and ran

```
docker run -p 5000:80 -e SDM_MASTER_KEY=00000000000000000000000000000000 icedevml/sdm-backend:build20220822-v2
```